# jQuery - how to destroy/unbind click event

Tags: jquery

In my application, i have calendar icon so when it is clicked the calendar pop up shows.

So, I have the following jQuery code which hides the section when i clicked anywhere of `<Div>` matching with `css` class.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myContent").click(function () {
        $(".calendar").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

However, the issue i am facing is it works fine for the first time

i.e. Click on Calendar Icon shows calendar popup.. than click on anywhere inside Div hides calendar pop-up.

However, When i reclick on Calendar icon than it does not show calendar popup unless i refresh the whole page.

I am guessing that i need to unbind click event but not sure how...
Any help please?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I see that you `hide` the calendar, when you display it again?

Comment: Yes i need to hide it only if it is displaying.

Comment: Is the calendar icon inside `.myContent`? Then use `event.stopPropagation` to keep the click event from bubbling out to the container.

Comment: add this condition if($(".calendar").is(':visible')){ $(".calendar").hide(); }

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are absolutely right. this calendar icon is inside  .myContent. How and where i can use event.stopPropagation in my code? please advise

Comment: $(".myContent").unbind('click',yourFunctionName);

Comment: as @Barmar suggested add click event with `event.stopPropagation ` on calendar icon  .. m i right Barmar?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code, maybe an executable stack snippet or jsfiddle, so we can understand what's going on. As currently written, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.stopPropagation` to keep the click on the calendar icon from bubbling out to `.myContent`:

```
$("#calendar_icon").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".calendar").show();
});
```

Comment: What is #calendar_icon in your example?

Comment: It's the ID of the calendar icon that you click on to display the calendar.

Comment: I already have stopPropagation() in my html line <button class=" btn btn-sm " type="button" id="CalendarSettings" ng-click="showCalendar();$event.stopPropagation();">.. I have method in my angular directive to show the calendar. However, i wrote this Jquery code in my HTML file to hide calendar pop-up... Not sure if i made you more confused or you getting my problem?

Comment: stopPropagation() still not solved my issue.. not sure im using it in righ way or not..

Comment: I don't know Angular, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

To unbind You can use off like:

```
$(".myContent").off('click');
```

Please refer:
[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use off.

```
var handler = function(){ /* whatever */ };
$(selector).on('click', handler);
$(selector).off('click', handler);
```

Alternatively if you only want it to happen at most one time...

```
$(selector).one('click', function(){ /* whatever */});
```

Comment: I don't think he really needs to unbind the handler, I think it's an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.myContent', function() {
        $(".calendar").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your angularjs but try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("click", ".myContent, function () {
           $(".calendar").hide();
     });

     $("#CalendarSettings").on("click", function()  {
           $(".calendar").show();
     });
  });
```